# A numeric mask does not work on dynamically added input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am beginner webdeveloper.
I write my project in jQuery.

I have this code:

```
<form class="reservation-form registration" method="post"
   action="{{ route('frontend.registerReservation') }}">
   @csrf
   <h4>User info</h4>
   <div class="field_wrapper">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
               <span class="form-label formMargin">Name</span>
               <input class="form-control childName" type="text"
                  name="child_name[]" placeholder="">
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-5">
            <div class="form-group">
               <span class="form-label formMargin">Birth date/span>
               <input class="form-control dateMask childDate" type="text"
                  name="child_date[]" placeholder="0000-00-00">
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-1 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="align-self-center add_button"><i
               class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-btn text-center">
      <button class="submit-btn reservation-btn">Booking</button>
   </div>
</form>


<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('.dateMask').mask('0000-00-00');
       $(".email").on({
           keydown: function (e) {
               if (e.which === 32)
                   return false;
           },
           change: function () {
               this.value = this.value.replace(/\s/g, "");
           }
       });
   
       $(".reservation-btn").hide();
       var check;
       $("#regulation").on("click", function () {
           check = $("#regulation").prop("checked");
           if (check) {
               $('.reservation-btn').show();
           } else {
               $('.reservation-btn').hide();
           }
       });
   
   
       $(".reservation-btn").click(function (e) {
               let email = $('.email').val();
               let name = $('.name').val();
               let phone = $('.phone').val();
               let date = $('.date').val();
   
               if (email != "" && name != "" && phone != "" && date != "") {
                   e.preventDefault(e);
                   $.ajax({
                       url: '{{ route('frontend.validation') }}?email=' + $(".email").val() + '&name=' + $(".name").val() + '&phone=' + $(".phone").val() + '&date=' + $(".date").val(),
                       type: 'get',
                       dataType: 'json',
                       headers: {
                           'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
                       },
                       cache: false,
                       success: function (response) {
                           if (response.status === "ok") {
   
                               var error = 0;
                               $('.childDate').each(function () {
                                   var element = $(this);
                                   // var name = element.val();
                                   var dateString = element.val();
   
                                   if(isDate18orMoreYearsOld(dateString) >= 18){
                                       error = 1;
                                       return false;
                                   }
   
                               });
                               if(error == 1){
                                   alert('Jeden z uczestników oznaczonych jako niepełnoletni ma 18 lat lub więcej!!');
                               } else {
                                   $(".registration").submit();
                               }
                           } else if (response.status === "error") {
                               alert(response.message)
                           }
                       }
                   });
               } else {
                   alert('Proszę uzupełnić wszystkie pola!');
               }
           }
       );
   
       function isDate18orMoreYearsOld(birthDateString) {
           var today = new Date();
           var birthDate = new Date(birthDateString);
           var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
           var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
           if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
               age--;
           }
           return age;
       }
   
       function validate2(date)
       {
           $.ajax({
               url: '{{ route('frontend.validation2') }}?date=' + date,
               type: 'get',
               dataType: 'json',
               cache: false,
               success: function (response) {
                   if (response.status === "ok") {
                       return 'ok';
                   } else if (response.status === "error") {
                       alert('Jeden z uczestników oznaczonych jako niepełnoletni ma 18 lat lub więcej!!');
                       e.preventDefault(e);
                   }
               }
           });
       }
   
   
       var maxField = 10;
       var addButton = $('.add_button');
       var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper');
       var fieldHTML = '<div class="row"><div class="col-lg-6"><div class="form-group"><span class="form-label formMargin">Name</span><input class="form-control childName" type="text" name="child_name[]" placeholder=""></div></div><div class="col-lg-5"><div class="form-group"><span class="form-label  formMargin">Birth date</span><input class="form-control childDate dateMask date" type="text" name="child_date[]" placeholder="0000-00-00"></div></div><div class="col-lg-1 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="align-self-center remove_button"><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div></div>';
       var x = 1;
   
       $(addButton).click(function () {
           if (x < maxField) {
               x++;
               $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML);
           }
       });
       $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function (e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           $(this).closest('.row').remove();
           x--;
       });
   
   });
</script>
```

With this code, I can add input dynamically to the form. It works fine. On the inputs I have added: $ ('. DateMask'). Mask ('0000-00-00'); - but it only works for input added while the page is loading (from html code). On these input. dynamically added does not work.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: `$('.dateMask').mask('0000-00-00');` runs on the elements that exist on the page at the time. If you add some elements after then you need to run either `$('.dateMask').mask('0000-00-00');` or you can run it on the new object when it has been created

Comment: how can I make it?

Comment: After you run `$(wrapper).append(fieldHTML);` use `$('.dateMask').mask('0000-00-00');`